# Cross Browser incompatibility? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, search, cross-browser, vbulletin

I'm not an internet guru by any means, I do however like to tinker around and build myself tools. One of my latest tools was an "advanced" search for a vb bulletin, they disabled some of the search options. I wrote up and tested in Google Chrome, works perfect. I cannot for the life of me figure out why it will not work in FF or IE.

The premises:
This page takes your query and search options, formats a url, and then opens it in a new window.

I have asked Q's here before, but typically have narrowed down the issue to a small amount of code. Since this is a cross browser issue, I have no clue how to approach releasing code. So what I will do is give the link to the site and ask you to check the source. I am also opened to any suggestions on how I can post the source here to make things easier.

Page:
http://advlolsearch.herobo.com/

JS:
http://advlolsearch.herobo.com/js/page.js

CSS:
http://advlolsearch.herobo.com/css/mystyle.css

Solved:
Heyooooooo! I found the issue. I needed to change:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var ID = event.target.id
```

to

```
$(".button").click(function(event) {
    var ID = event.target.id
```

Chrome understood what I was doing but FF wanted to derp out on me. Thanks for the help all. Leaving this open though because I have a few running questions in the comments.

Comment: That's a might big if/else statement. Have you considered using a map/array/etc. and eliminate it in favor of simple data structures?

Comment: Define "will not work".  What does happen?  Do you have errors on your console?

Comment: Since you're trying to do `window.open()`, are you getting any warnings about a popup being blocked?  Each browser has it's own logic for what it blocks/allows and has settings that affect the logic too.

Comment: No warnings saying pop ups are blocked. When I click the buttons at the bottom nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a comment (not an answer), but I can't put significant chunks of code in a comment so I'll put it here since I think it would be helpful.  This is probably not your cross browser issue (I suspect that's caused by popup blocking), but you really ought to DRY out your code and remove all the repeated pieces of code by putting all the data into a table and looking it up from a table with one short piece of code like this:

```
...
if (val=="forum") {
    var selectedforum = $('#select').val();
    var searchby = $('input:radio[name=search]:checked').val();
    var showas = $('input:radio[name=show]:checked').val();
    var dataLookup = {
        na: {
            all: [],
            np: [29],
            tg: [29],
            mm: [48,49,43],
            sr: [48],
            tw: [49],
            dm: [43],
            ll: [9,2,16,41,23,15,20,32]
            // ... put the rest here
        },
        euw: {
            all: [],
            np: [4]
            // rest of the data here
        },
        eune: {
            all: [],
            np: [4]
            // rest of the data here
        }
    };
    if (region in dataLookup) {
        var data = dataLookup[region];
        if (selectedForum in data) {
            fID = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data[selectedForum].length; i++) {
                fID += "&forumchoice[]=" + data[selectedForum][i];
            }
            var theURL = "http://" + region + ".leagueoflegends.com/board/search.php?do=process&query=" + query + fID + "&titleonly=" + searchby + "&showposts=" + showas;
            theURl = theURL.replace(' ','%20');
            window.open(theURL);
        }
    }
} else if ...
```

Comment: I really like the the code above. However, when I add the data the I get"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" thrown in the javascript console. My test page is here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12531574/ADVLolSearch/index.html Thoughts?

Comment: Did you look at the referenced line number in the error message?  It shows you have a missing comma at the end of the `cd: [35]` line.

Comment: I may have found the issue, I was missing some , after the []. Firefox error console caught that but Chrome didnt. Ah jfriend ninja posted. I am still tinkering. I want to give proper credit in the source. Any preferences as to how I credit you?

Comment: For credit, how about an upvote on my answer here?  Nothing else required.  It's just advice on programming technique.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for learning more about these datasets. I have upvoted you, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the votes.  I'm not sure what kind of info you want.  These data declarations are just javascript objects being declared.  The `{ }` syntax is the declaration of an object and the `np: [29]` syntax is the declaration of a property named `np` with a value of `[29]` which is an array with one value in it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6068/discussion-between-aaron-henderson-and-jfriend00)